# How to add product in magento?see atteched image

Tags: magento-1.9

How to add following type of product.
select radio button for product.
I am new in magento.
I have try using Tier Price.how to display radio button?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can you custom options to do that. Go to edit product screen, select "custom options", then select input type - radio buttons, add options